# Play audio directly from Lambda /tmp folder

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I'm currently building a Alexa application in Node with Lambda. I have the need to convert and merge several audio files. I'm currently creating an audio file using google text-to-speech (long story on the need for it) which I write to /tmp and pulling an audio file from s3 which I also write to /tmp. I'm then using sox to merge the two files (see below) and write back to S3 (currently public) which I then have hard coded to play that particular clip.

My question is if it is possible to play audio directly from the /tmp folder as opposed to having to write the file back to S3.

```
await lambdaAudio.sox('-m /tmp/google-formatted.mp3 /tmp/audio.mp3 /tmp/result.mp3')

// get data from resulting mp3
const data = await readFile('/tmp/result.mp3');
const base64data = new Buffer(data, 'binary');

// put file back on AWS for playing
s3.putObject({
  Bucket: 'my-bucket',
  Key: 'result.mp3',
  Body: base64data,
  ACL:'public-read'
},function (resp) {
  console.log('Done');
});

return`<audio src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/my-bucket/result.mp3" />`;
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually upload the lambda function zipping the code and modules and in general all the files that my code requires.
https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/post/Tx1UE9W1NQ0GYII/Publishing-Your-Skill-Code-to-Lambda-via-the-Command-Line-Interface
So if you zip the /tmp directory and publish it as part of your lambda code the audio file will be accessible by your lambda function

Comment: unfortunately this audio dialog needs to be created on the fly, writing to the /tmp folder then read so uploading it isn't an option.